# How to select the raster font for the Windows console?

Tags: python, windows, fonts, console

I want to select the **Raster Font** from the console so I can have "Pixel like" characters in the console which are 8x8 pixels big. It's because I have programmed a console game engine and now I want it to look nicer.

Here is my code for changing the font and the size:

```
import ctypes

LF_FACESIZE = 32
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

class CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("nFont", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFontSize", COORD),
                ("FontFamily", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FontWeight", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FaceName", ctypes.c_wchar * LF_FACESIZE)]

font = CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX()
font.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)
font.nFont = 12
font.dwFontSize.X = 11
font.dwFontSize.Y = 18
font.FontFamily = 54
font.FontWeight = 400
font.FaceName = "Lucida Console"

handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
        handle, ctypes.c_long(False), ctypes.pointer(font))
```

Comment: I dont see a question nor an error description ...

Comment: I get no errors but i cant figure out how to set the Raster Font as the console Font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the correct font name to make each character 8 by 8 big:

```
import ctypes

LF_FACESIZE = 32
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

class CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("nFont", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFontSize", COORD),
                ("FontFamily", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FontWeight", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FaceName", ctypes.c_wchar * LF_FACESIZE)]

font = CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX()
font.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)
font.nFont = 8
font.dwFontSize.X = 8
font.dwFontSize.Y = 8
font.FontFamily = 8
font.FontWeight = 8
font.FaceName = "Terminal"

handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
        handle, ctypes.c_long(False), ctypes.pointer(font))
```